# Как сделать обрезку изображения css

Tags: html, css

Хочу обрезать изображение ровно по краям. Width и Height просто сжимают картинку. Нужно, что бы мсштаб остался прежним

Comment: object-fit в помощь

Comment: Какое мне нужно значение поставить для обрезки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы изображение не теряло свои пропорции при смене размера используйте [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Для изменения "позиции" используйте [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-position), по дефолту значение `center center`;

Пример:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.resize {
  display: block;
  min-width: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="resize">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/biWjJAg.png">
</div>

<div class="resize">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/biWjJAg.png" style="object-fit: cover;">
</div>
```

Слева блок без `object-fit`, справа с `object-fit: cover;`

Блоки можно растягивать и увидеть поведение.

Comment: Поставил, но изображение сжималось при выставленном Width и Height. Поставил эти значения в картинку, а не див

Comment: Оно уменьшается в размерах, а не обрезается